# File not found Exception occurs

Tags: c#, winforms, filenotfoundexception, imagelist

I have a image list in my project. So i need to add images in the image list from the code behind window.

I have a Folder in my project which is called Myimages. In that folder i have some images.

So i try like this:

```
imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"Myimages\dog.ico"));
```

or

```
imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"~\Myimages\cat.ico"));
```

or

```
 imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"/Myimages/horse.ico"));
```

But i can't able to do like this. It makes **FileNotFoundException**.

**Error:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: /Myimages/horse.ico

how to solve this error. Helps Appreciated!!

When i used full path like `C:\MyProject\Myimages\horse.ico`. Its working for me. 
But when i give path like "`Myimages\horse.ico`" it gives exception.

Comment: What kind of application it is? Web or Windows? In case of windows application, the application runs from the bin folder so it won't be able to find the file based on the relative file if it's not right.

Comment: Did you set the image build action as content and Copy always ? Can you find it in the Debug folder after that ?

Comment: The current path is the `Debug` or `Release` folder in your solution. Depending on your targeting configuration

Comment: "image build action as content and Copy always" what is it mean?.i m sorry i cant get you info @user3185569

Comment: its debug folder @Jimbot

Comment: At least to begin with, the simplest reliable solution is to base configuration like this with a configuration file. I.e. the app.config file. Under <appSettings> add a setting called "imagePath" with a value set to an absolute (or relative) path, then in your code uses ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imagePath"] in place of the hard-coded path. This way you can easily change this value without rebuilding your app.

Comment: @user8331467 do you have an extra solution folder? is it named as your Project?

Comment: Yes.. the folder named as my project name @MongZhu

Answer (score 2):

> When i used full path like `C:\MyProject\Myimages\horse.ico`. Its working for me. But when i give path like `Myimages\horse.ico` it gives exception.

Because a relative path is search from the location of the *.EXE file. This is in the `C:\MyProject\bin\Debug` or `C:\MyProject\bin\Release` folder. You need to move 2 folder up before diving into `Myimages`. Try this relative path:

> `..\..\Myimages\horse.ico`

EDIT:

If your solution folder has the same name as your project folder then you are one level deeper then I thought. Please try in this case one level more

> `..\..\..\Myimages\horse.ico`

Disclaimer: this approach will bring you into trouble as soon as you move your *.EXE relative to the `MyImages` folder. For example into the same folder, then this path will be wrong.

EDIT 2: Please you the following format:

```
imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"..\..\..\Myimages\horse.ico"));
```

Comment: Although this will mess up as soon as the .exe is moved. Maybe you should put the images in the projects embedded resources.

Comment: The same thing happene An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: ..\..\Myimages\horse.ico

Comment: @user8331467 have a look at my edit. if `MyImages` is in the solution folder? then try: `..\..\..\Myimages\horse.ico`

Comment: `Additional information: ..\..\..\Myimages\horse.ico`.. Its again show the exception

Comment: @user8331467 did you place the `@` before the string?

Answer (score 1):

When working with *relative paths* e.g.

```
 @"/MyImages/horse.ico"
```

The actual full path is

```
 Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"/MyImages/horse.ico");
```

Please, inspect `Environment.CurrentDirectory` value and you can see where the system tries to look for `/Myimages/horse.ico` file. You can modify the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` if you want:

```
 // When relative path provided look at C:\MyFiles
 Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\MyProject";
```

**Edit:** When you don' want setting absolute paths (e.g. `@"C:\MyProject"`) as default ones, you can try computing the path starting from the *entry point assembly* (e.g. exe file)

```
using System.Reflection;

...

// One level down the directory where exe file lies
string path = 
  Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "..");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I want to only mention project containing folder name and image name. is this  posibile to do?

Comment: @user8331467: what do actually you want to mention and in *which format*, please? `MyProject` and `horse.ico`? `C:\MyProject`, `/MyImages/horse.ico`?

Comment: `/MyImages/horse.ico` like this

Comment: not allowed to mention directory.. solution containing Myimages folder name and image name.

Comment: @user8331467: you can try setting the default path relatively to the main assembly (exe file or alike) somthing  like this: `string path =  Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "..");`

Answer (score 0):

If Web Application is the case. Then make the use of Server.MapPath

```
string fileRelativePath = "~/Content/Gallery/" + Path.GetFileName(path);
image.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileRelativePath));
```

Comment: It is winform application